# Why is the full_name field not being populated when customer submits payment form in Django and Stripe integration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm having trouble retrieving the customer's name when they submit a payment form in my Django application. I'm using Django for the backend and Stripe for payment processing. The customer's name is not being saved in the database when the form is submitted.

I have a 'add' view that handles the form submission and creates an order. Here's the relevant code:

views.py:

```
`from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from basket.basket import Basket

from .models import Order, OrderItem

def add(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        order_key = request.POST.get('order_key')
        cust_name = request.POST.get('custName')  # Get the custName value 

        user_id = request.user.id
        baskettotal = basket.get_total_price()

        if Order.objects.filter(order_key=order_key).exists():
            pass
        else:
            order = Order.objects.create(user_id=user_id, full_name=cust_name, address1='add1', address2='add2', total_paid=baskettotal, order_key=order_key)
            order_id = order.pk

            for item in basket:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order_id=order_id, product=item['product'], price=item['price'], quantity=item['qty'])

        response = JsonResponse({'success': 'Return something'})
        return response
`
```

The form submission is handled by the following JavaScript code:

```
script.js:

var stripe = Stripe('');

var elem = document.getElementById('submit');
clientsecret = elem.getAttribute('data-secret');

var elements = stripe.elements();
var style = {
    base: {
        color: "#000",
        lineHeight: '2.4',
        fontSize: '16px'
    }
};

var card = elements.create("card", { style: style });
card.mount("#card-element");

card.on('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors')
    if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        $('#card-errors').addClass('alert alert-info');
    } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
        $('#card-errors').removeClass('alert alert-info');
    }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var custName = document.getElementById("custName").value;
    var custAdd = document.getElementById("custAdd").value;
    var custAdd2 = document.getElementById("custAdd2").value;
    var postCode = document.getElementById("postCode").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/add/',
        data: {
            order_key: clientsecret,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRF_TOKEN,
            action: "post",
            custName: custName
        },
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json.success)

            stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientsecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: card,
                    billing_details: {
                        address:{
                            line1:custAdd,
                            line2:custAdd2
                        },
                        name: custName
                    },
                }
            }).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    console.log('payment error')
                    console.log(result.error.message);
                } else {
                    if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                        console.log('payment processed')
                        window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment/orderplaced/");
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {},
    });
});
```

When I submit the payment form, I receive the following error:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: orders_order.full_name
[22/May/2023 16:15:01] "POST /orders/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 159681

I'm not sure why the full_name field is not being populated even though I'm retrieving the custName value from the form and passing it to the create method of the Order model. Any help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

here is my orders model if needed:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

from store.models import Product


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_user')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    order_key = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    billing_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.created)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,
                              related_name='items',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,
                                related_name='order_items',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "../store/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Payment{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<style>
  .account-form input,
    {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    height: calc(2em + .75rem + 2px);
  }

  .form-control {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
  }

  .account-form input:focus {
    border-color: #1497ff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="login d-flex align-items-center py-5">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="payment-form" class="col-12 col-lg-6 mx-auto">
              <h3 class="mb-3">Billing address</h3>
              <!-- Error messages in this element -->
              <div id="card-errors" class="a" role="alert"></div>
              <form>
                <div class="row g-3">
                  <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <label for="custName" class="form-label">Customer Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="custName" placeholder="" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Valid first name is required.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="custAdd" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter your shipping address.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <label for="address2" class="form-label">Address 2 <span
                        class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="custAdd2" placeholder="Apartment or suite">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <label for="country" class="form-label">Country</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="country" required>
                      <option value="">Choose...</option>
                      <option>United States</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please select a valid country.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="state" class="form-label">State</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="state" required>
                      <option value="">Choose...</option>
                      <option>California</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please provide a valid state.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="Postcode" class="form-label">Postcode</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postCode" placeholder="" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Zip code required.
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>
                <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
                <div id="card-element" class="form-control form-control-payment">
                  <!-- Payment elements will appear here -->
                </div>
                <hr class="my-4">
                <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 fw-bold" data-secret="{{ client_secret }}">Pay</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
    {% comment %} Make csrf token availble in JS files {% endcomment %}
    var CSRF_TOKEN = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="{% static 'payment/index.js' %}" data-rel-js></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Add 'print(cust_name)' and check the value is received by add() view. Does it works?

Comment: can you post your template and forms.py